# SQLite INTEGER optimization

Tags: database-design, sqlite, database-optimization

I'm trying to strip some extra size from an SQLite database I'm pulling from one of my WebServices to an iOS app. I'm doing some separate tests what makes tables bigger than they have to be.

I have a prices table which has about 223k records. By merely converting 2 REAL columns to INTEGER * 100, already gave me 34% back on my table's size in kilobytes. Which was actually shocking..

Because I noticed this absurd difference I checked just having 1 table with 1 column of the INTEGER type with the same (223k) records.

So here's what I noticed (I `VACUUM` after every test):

- Filling all rows with either `NULL`, `0` or `1` results in an 1,9MB file
- Filling all rows with `100` results in a 2,1MB file
- Filling all rows with `1000`-`10000` results in a 2,4MB file
- Filling all rows with `100000` results in a 3,0MB file
- Filling all rows with `10000000` results in a 3,1MB file

I really feels like there's an overhead on the dynamic of the INTEGER field-type. Isn't there a cheaper way to store `int` values in SQLite or this is the only end-game to go with?

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly deduced the internal storage types used in SQLite's [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

The best way to reduce the size of the data to be downloaded over the web is to compress the file.

Comment: Yeah I already use gzip compression which is a major win, but I'm just very disappointed to lose such big amount of kilobytes over mere integers. I'm strongly considering using JSON to bypass this.

Comment: @Allendar JSON also has variable-length integers, since they are stored as text. The integer digits alone for storing 223k `10000000`s would need 1.7MB of space.